# Tooltip is missing in stack overflow logo

Tags: bug, logo, tooltips

Tooltip is missing on stack overflow logo

[image]

Comment: So was it missing, or is it? If it is, what should it be?

Comment: Actually as per the user interface we should provide title attribute if we are using any icon or image.

Comment: _"as per the user interface"_ - I think you accidentally a word.

Comment: @CodeCaster Then why we are providing tool tip for other icons?

Comment: I'm not the one to answer that. I'm telling you that your question is unclear (**was** it missing or **is** it missing?), I'm asking what the title **should** be according to you and I'm asking what you mean exactly by _"as per the user interface"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster Doesn’t “as per” just mean “according to”? Or is something else unclear?

Comment: @Xufox it means "In accordance with" so yeah "according to" fits as well

Comment: @CodeCaster  They mean the other images/logos on the navbar (like the notifications icon, the achievements, etc) all have tooltips so the logo should too.

Comment: :O Sorry for my poor English. I'll go to learn English then I'll come back here. Let start  **`A B C D E ........ XZYR.....PST.....`**

Comment: @RameshRajendran I'm assuming it was intentional but, that comment really hurts to read.

Comment: @Xufox May be am a very popular person in this web site. :( :P

Comment: How about you gather all these non-issues in a document, then suggest all those changes in ___one___ question, in a month or so? Then we don't have to vote on a daily basis...

Comment: @Cerbrus . :p  I will try.. But I asked another question while you typing your comment. OOPS!

Comment: As a warning: people are starting to get very tired with the series of poorly-researched and poorly-asked questions you've posted lately to Meta. This is resulting in multiple flags. Because a question ban does not exist on Meta.SO, our only recourse to get you to stop will be to suspend your main account. Please don't let it come to that, and take a bit more time to research and think through these questions.

Comment: Before you come here with yet another non-sensical suggestion..... Next time you have an idea: look at it, try to understand WHY your idea would improve the site (like for this proposal, you have no real justification as to why it should be there), then research and take the time to PROPERLY explain it.... seriously, this is getting to be a bit much by now :/.

Answer (score 10):

There is no standard that says [images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) or [anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) tags ***must*** have a title attribute.

Since ***none*** of the buttons next to that one have a `title` attribute, it's only consistent for that one not to have one either.